# Open file menu bug with ubuntu dark theme

Tags: linux

I'm using *Mathematica* on a Ubuntu with a dark theme. When I click on the open file menu option, it shows up with a white background and white letters. I can only see something if the folder or file is clicked because it's highlighted (screenshot below). Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience in Linux, but just to make sure, your question is about *Mathematica*, right?

Comment: Question editted to help clarify the problem. Yes, problem is with mathematica.

Comment: @HugoAndrade I'd suggest including a screenshot if possible.  Sorry, personally I'm not experiences enough with Linux to be able to help, but visual things are easier to understand thus increase the chance of an answer.  In the meantime you have my reopen vote.